# How to pass parameters and resource bundle from master report to subreport

Tags: java, internationalization, jasper-reports, subreport

Currently I'm using *JasperReports* to generate pdfs displaying a list of payments, one entity per page. Code for that (for one entity):

```
 Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path + "WEB-INF/jasper/PaymentOrder.jasper");
                report = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

What I need to do is to display two enitities in one file. I'm trying to use subreports to do that.

1. How can I pass a Map with parameters to my subreport?
2. And how to I change my subreport file (if needed) to get parameters from parent?
3. How can I pass ResourceBundle from master report to subreport?
4. How can I set the name of subreport?

Master report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <title>
        <band height="531" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" isUnderline="false" pdfEncoding="UTF-8" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["* MASTER REPORT *"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport runToBottom="false">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="55" width="555" height="15" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get( "subReport1Params" )]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get( "subReport1" )]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Subreport:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <title>
        <band height="531" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" isUnderline="false" pdfEncoding="UTF-8" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}.getString( "user" ) + ": "+$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get( "user" )]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="22" width="555" height="22"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" isUnderline="false" pdfEncoding="UTF-8" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}.getString( "payment" ) + " № "+$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get( "docNumber" )+" "+$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}.getString( "from" ) + " "+$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get( "date" )]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

java code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> parameters = getParametersForPayment(doc1, user, locale);
String path = ((WebApplication) Application.get()).getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

File fileSubReport1 = new File(path + "WEB-INF/jasper/PaymentOrder.jasper");
parameters.put("subReport1", JRLoader.loadObject(fileSubReport1));


File f = new File(path + "WEB-INF/jasper/PaymentMaster.jasper");
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(f);
report = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Comment: @AlexK, the first one is not suitable for me because I don't have a list of same objects, they are different. I need to dynamically load jasper files based on types of objects I have (for example, paymentA.jasper for paymentA, paymentB.jasper for paymentB). In the second they are passing REPORT_DATA_SOURCE from main to subreport. But I am not getting data from JRDataSource, I am getting data from Hashmap (i.e. $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get( "amount" ))

Comment: And what is the problem you faced? You can use **subreportExpression** + pass *REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP* to subreport

Comment: @AlexK I tried <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></dataSourceExpression>, the error is 'java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource'

Comment: You should post the small sample (main report + subreport)

Answer (score 8):

### Questions

#### How can I pass a Map with parameters to my subreport?

You are right, you can pass parameters via ***REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP*** parameter or with help of ***subreportParameter***, ***subreportParameterExpression***.

#### How can I set the name of subreport?

You can use ***subreportExpression*** with parameters.

#### How can I pass ResourceBundle from master report to subreport?

In case you are passing the ***REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP*** to the subreport you do not need to do anything else.

---

You was so close to solve your task. Your mistakes are:

1. You did not set the **resourceBundle** attribute for the report - to use the `$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}`
2. You did not pass **REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP** parameter to the subreport with help of ***parametersMapExpression*** - to use parameters in subreport

Another recommendation is too add parameters declaration in template. It is easier to support reports in this case and it is a *good style*.

---

### The working example

The main report and two subreports will be used in example. The name of the subreport to use will be passed via parameters from *Java* code. I'll add internationalization support for *en_US* locale. Only parameters will be used for showing data (without any datasource).

#### Resource bundle

The small resource bundle *master_en_US.properties* is using.

```
user=User:
payment=Payment:
from=From:
```

#### Master report's template

There are two ways if we are passing ALL parameters from the *Java* code: we can declare parameters in *jrxml* file or we can skip this step. As I said, I prefer the variant with declaration in template (first case).

In first case the template will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="master" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" resourceBundle="master" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
    <parameter name="user" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="docNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="subReportName" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["subreport_1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="241" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="326" height="59" uuid="f629d1c8-658f-4ae0-a492-2912a7868e96"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subReportName} + ".jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

And in the second case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="master" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" resourceBundle="master" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
    <title>
        <band height="241" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="326" height="59" uuid="f629d1c8-658f-4ae0-a492-2912a7868e96"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("subReportName") + ".jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Subreports

The one subreport will be with parameters declaration block and another one - without.

The *subreport_1.jrxml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subreport_1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
    <parameter name="user" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="docNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="400" height="15" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}.getString("user") + " " + $P{user}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="25" width="400" height="15" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}.getString("payment") + " № " + $P{docNumber} + " " +
$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}.getString("from") + " " + $P{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The *subreport_2.jrxml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subreport_2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="400" height="15" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}.getString("user") + " " + $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("user")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

#### The Java code

```
String subreportName;
// some code
JasperReport jasperReport;
try (InputStream inputStream = JRLoader.getResourceInputStream("master.jrxml")) {
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream));
}

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.US);
params.put("user", "Bruce Wayne");
params.put("docNumber", "Some #");
params.put("date", "03.06.2010");
if (!isNullOrEmpty(subreportName)) {
    params.put("subReportName", subreportName); // the default name in this case will be set in master report (<defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["subreport_1"]]></defaultValueExpression>) 
}
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

#### Output result

I've used the *PDFExporter* and in case of *subreport_1* the result will be:

[image: The generated pdf file]

in case of *subreport_2* the result will be:

[image: The generated pdf file]

---

***Notes:***

- The *[Internationalized Report Templates](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/i18n/index.html)* topic will help to understand the main concept of internationalization support in *JasperReports*
- The *[Subreport Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/subreport/index.html#subreports)* helps to understand how to use subreports

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I changed my subreport section to make it look like your's (parametersMapExpression & connectionExpression). I didn't change my subreport. I put resource bundle in my parameters like this `parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE, resBundle)`.  You said that I "did not set the resourceBundle attribute for the report", but I'm not sure where to set it and why I need to do so.
 If I generate my subreport only it works fine. But if I try to do so with my master report, subreport is just not displaid.

Comment: You are welcome :) `<jasperReport ... resourceBundle="master"  .. >` - it is a header of master's report. You can set it in iReport/JSS or manually

Comment: I've added it to my master report, but nothing has changed. PDF is still empty. Btw, what is weird is that when I change my subreport attribute to whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" pdf is not even generated, it just hangs. (I've also edited the post, added java code there)

Comment: Did you try to change the type of *subReport1* parameter to *JasperReport* class? Is the code of *jrxml* files in your post is actual (after adding resourceBundle)? Did you try my example? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

1. In main (Parent file)
2. In sub (child file)
   `enter code here`
3. In Java file
   ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application", new LOCALE("en"));

HashMap parameters = new HashMap();  parameters.put("REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE", resourceBundle);
JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, source);